# Excel VBA memory issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge data (16 files with 300,000 rows and 65 columns in each) in excel. I am trying to analyse the data via vba (For each file the recordset takes the data based on criteria). For 12 files it works, however when I increase the files involved the vba just dies, after opening and taking the information from 12th file.

```
connectionToDatabase.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & CStr(file) & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
connectionToDatabase.CursorLocation = adUseClient
recordsTable.Open "SELECT a, b,c,d ... z, where z>10000"
```

It does some arithmetic here and then

```
recordsTable.Close
connectionToDatabase.Close
Set recordsTable = Nothing
Set connectionToDatabase = Nothing
```

Comment: With that much data, I strongly suggest to move it to MS Access database and handle it there.

Comment: And make sure to use the 64bit edition of Office which an handle more memory than the usually used 32bit edition.

Comment: It will exceed the capacity of Access (2GB). It doesn't matter if I use 32bit or 64 bit Excel

Comment: is the above script running 16 times or just once?

Comment: It is in a for loop and runs several times until it has opened and taken the necessary info from all files in specific folder

Comment: Unless **absolutely** necessary for backward compatibility I'd use a server-side cursor and not a `.CursorLocation = adUseClient`. Also, if you're opening them read-only then I'd use a `.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly`. BTW, I just used your code on a file containing one million rows without a problem. No, I didn't iterate over it 12+ times. Nonetheless, if your machine cannot handle these files then there is little we can do to help. I (personally) would move to a DB server (MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle DB Express or any other). Makes it easier and much faster.

Comment: Perhaps a PowerQuery solution is helpful here?

Comment: Thank you Ralph for feedback, I run the script on very powerful machine, hence I don't think it's hardware problem here, I think maybe there is some limitation with recordset object and if yes how can I avoid it